# Parity of the surface state in a Topological Insulator (TI)?

Tags: topological-insulators, parity

Please bear with this experimentalist trying to understand the subtleties of TIs in what may well be imprecise language. I appreciate that one can deduce the topological trivial or non-trivial nature of a filled band for particular crystalline structures by virtue of $(-1)^{\nu_0} = \Pi \delta_i$ taken over the [TR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry) symmetry points of the [BZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone). I also appreciate that the gap must close at the interface between topologically distinct insulating phases. In my naive understanding, I would expect that the surface state must "fix" the overall parity difference between the valence bands of the TI and trivial insulator and believe that $N_k = \Delta \nu$ mod 2, where $N_k$ is the number of Kramers pair edge modes implies this fix. I would have expected however that their would be some implication about the parity of the edge mode itself (i.e. that is must be odd). Why is there no statement about the edge modes parity?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your expression: $N_k = \Delta \nu$ mod 2. In which reference did you see it? The number of Kramers pairs at the boundary of a TI (2D or 3D) depends on the details of the material. It's parity, however, is always odd (even) for a TI (trivial insulator). For example, Bi$_{1-x}$Sb$_{x}$ has either 3 or 5 Dirac cones depending on the chemical potential. However, (say) Bi$_2$Se$_3$ has only 1 Dirac cone. Note that they are both odd.